# send error while running expect code

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I made an expect code:

*#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ls

expect "*]$*"

send "cd /to/some/path\n"

expect "*]$*"

send "sudo -u root ./program.sh"

expect  "*:*"

send "i_am_password\n"

interact*

while executing it I am getting the below error:

*spawn ls

my_pgm.exp  abc.sh  axyz.zip  all.zip  test.exp

send: spawn id exp6 not open

    while executing

"send "cd /to/some/path\n""

    (file "./my_pgm.exp" line 5)*

I am running this code on ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: Don't do this! It's terrible!

Comment: What you should do instead is update [/etc/sudoers](http://man.cx/visudo) to allow you to `sudo program.sh` without having to enter your password. As a principle, never hard-code your password in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to really understand why you need expect, but for a bash script, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn bash -i
expect "*$ "
send "cd /to/some/path\n"
expect "*$ "
send "sudo -u root ./program.sh\n"
expect "*: "
send "i_am_password\n"
interact
```

**Description**

The `spawn` directive instruct *expect* **which** program are to be used to interact with. So if you **want** to interact with bash, you have to ask `expect`to `spawn bash`. The `-i` parameter to bash enforce them to start in *interactive* mode.

At all, **this look like a very bad idea**, but that's only my opinion ;)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks! ;-) Happy to see: *I'm not alone to think so*. :->>